ApexCharts.js brush option enabled error: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: ApexCharts is not defined
I am trying to create a candlestick combo chart per example shown in the ApexCharts example Apex Candlestick Charts
I use Vite, and am importing it from the node_modules folder via:
import ApexCharts from "apexcharts";
and then attempting to render it:


let options = {
    series: [
      {
        data: chartData,
      },
    ],
    chart: {
      type: "candlestick",
      height: 300,
      id: "mainCandle",
      toolbar: {
        autoSelected: "pan",
        show: true,
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: true,
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    plotOptions: {
      candlestick: {
        colors: {
          upward: "#3C90EB",
          downward: "#DF7D46",
        },
      },
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: "datetime",
    },
  };

  chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart-candlestick"), options);
  chart.render();

  let optionsBar = {
    series: [
      {
        name: "volume",
        data: chartData,
      },
    ],
    chart: {
      height: 150,
      type: "candlestick",
      brush: {
        enabled: true,
        target: "mainCandle",
        autoScaleYaxis: true,
      },
      toolbar: {
        autoSelected: "pan",
        show: true,
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      selection: {
        enabled: true,
        xaxis: {
          min: new Date("01 Jul 2024").getTime(),
          max: new Date("04 Sep 2024").getTime(),
        },
        fill: {
          color: "#ccc",
          opacity: 0.4,
        },
        stroke: {
          color: "#0D47A1",
        },
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        columnWidth: "80%",
        colors: {
          ranges: [
            {
              from: -1000,
              to: 0,
              color: "#F15B46",
            },
            {
              from: 1,
              to: 10000,
              color: "#FEB019",
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    stroke: {
      width: 0,
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: "datetime",
      axisBorder: {
        offsetX: 13,
      },
    },
    yaxis: {
      labels: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
  };

  chartBar = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart-bar"), optionsBar);
  chartBar.render();`



The 1st chart renders as expected, but the 2nd chart gives the error: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: ApexCharts is not defined
This only seems to error out if the brush option is turned on like so:


chart: {
  brush: { 
    enabled: true,
    target: "target",
    }
}



Open to suggestions. =)
